# Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 - Problems saving preferences while importing a JUnit 4 test to the package

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, package

I have the problem that I can't import **JUnit 4** test into a `package` anymore without getting the window **"Problems saving preferences"**. I tried to delete the `.settings` folder but it didn't help at all.

I think it all happened when I used a special theme. However, I already restored everything to their defaults and removed themes and it still doesn't seem to work.

edit://.log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-04-17 19:32:15.720
!MESSAGE Problems saving preferences.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.service.prefs.BackingStoreException: Exception saving preferences to: C:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/H²­    PK   ±JaH2Ú¢Ä  a                   a3.prefs.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.write(EclipsePreferences.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.save(EclipsePreferences.java:1135)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.save(EclipsePreferences.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalFlush(EclipsePreferences.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.flush(EclipsePreferences.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalFlush(EclipsePreferences.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.flush(EclipsePreferences.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.flush(RootPreferences.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyPreferences(PreferencesService.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesImportPage1.transfer(WizardPreferencesImportPage1.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesPage.finish(WizardPreferencesPage.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.PreferencesImportWizard.performFinish(PreferencesImportWizard.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ImportResourcesAction.run(ImportResourcesAction.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: Worst case: just throw away your workspace and start fresh again. If you think you can't do that because it would take you 2 hours to get your workspace and projects configured again; that would be even more a reason to look into doing that ... from the perspective of: reasonable project setup should allow you to do that in 5, 10 minutes, maximum ;-)